# Service for Node.js app monitoring - OpBeat alternative

Tags: node.js, performance, error-handling, monitoring, pm2

I used OpBeat to monitor my Node.js on production. Unfortunately, this service has been closed recently. I am looking for alternatives for error tracking (the most important thing), performance monitoring etc. I know, that I can use logs, but external service may be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PM2.  I use it for error tracking, monitoring and deployment
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

```
npm install pm2 -g |

pm2 start app.js
```

Comment: Hm.. I use pm2 to start and running app in background, didn't know that it can also error tracking!

Comment: Yeah, I used it for that at first only then discovered all the other stuff it can do.  It even has its own dashboard, https://app.keymetrics.io/#/

Comment: let me know if there are any questions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your app, but most people running Node also have other tools, along with Web frontends, mobile apps, etc. You likely can use an APM tool (leaders include AppDynamics, Dynatrace, and New Relic). They all monitor Node.js and other technologies as they work together. Instead, if you use a tool like PM2 you end up with lots of tools to monitor versus just having one. Sure PM2 is free, but it's not free when you look at your time to set up the tool, configure it, upgrade it. Then using it to identify and troubleshoot issues is also difficult if you have to keep changing tools and UIs. It really depends on your situation and goals.